# MVC Export to Excel from HTML Table in div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am trying to implement Export to excel functionality. I am passing my entire table in html format as string to the export function and trying to convert it into excel. Following is the code i have implemented

```
        [HttpPost]
    public void ExportToExcel(ExportDataEntity data)
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.WriteLine(data.HtmlData);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.Unicode);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

Following is my Entity class

```
    public class ExportDataEntity
{
    public string HtmlData { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileFormat { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the Table structure

```
<table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2">Col1</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Col2</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Col3</th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2">Col4</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Col5</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="6">Col6</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SubCol21</td>
                    <td>SubCol22</td>
                    <td>SubCol23</td>
                    <td>SubCol31</td>
                    <td>SubCol32</td>
                    <td>SubCol33</td>
                    <td>SubCol51</td>
                    <td>SubCol52</td>
                    <td>SubCol53</td>
                    <td>SubCol54</td>
                    <td>SubCol61</td>
                    <td>SubCol62</td>
                    <td>SubCol63</td>
                    <td>SubCol64</td>
                    <td>SubCol65</td>
                    <td>SubCol66</td>
                </tr>
                    <tr class="trData">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Count</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Met %</td>
                    <td  colspan="3">1</td>
                    <td colspan="3">2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="3">3</td>
                    <td colspan="3">4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I am calling the ExportToExcel function via ajax call and passing entire html inside the div( consist only  ). I am not getting any error in my code nor in my browser window.

I have googled alot and tried to implement various solution but nothing helped me.

Please do let me know what is the mistake I am doing, also provide the best solution to implement it in MVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you already have data in Frontend then you can use Jquery Plugin table2Excel to directly export your table data to excel file. You dont need to call any server side code :
Below is the Example for the same :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
        function exportToExcel() {  
            $("#tableData").table2excel({  
                name: "Table2Excel",  
                filename: "myFileName",  
                fileext: ".xls"  
            });  
        }  
</script>

</head>
<body>


<table id="tableData" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2">Col1</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Col2</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Col3</th>
                    <th class="text-center" rowspan="2">Col4</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="4">Col5</th>
                    <th class="text-center" colspan="6">Col6</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>SubCol21</td>
                    <td>SubCol22</td>
                    <td>SubCol23</td>
                    <td>SubCol31</td>
                    <td>SubCol32</td>
                    <td>SubCol33</td>
                    <td>SubCol51</td>
                    <td>SubCol52</td>
                    <td>SubCol53</td>
                    <td>SubCol54</td>
                    <td>SubCol61</td>
                    <td>SubCol62</td>
                    <td>SubCol63</td>
                    <td>SubCol64</td>
                    <td>SubCol65</td>
                    <td>SubCol66</td>
                </tr>
                    <tr class="trData">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td>18</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Count</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Met %</td>
                    <td  colspan="3">1</td>
                    <td colspan="3">2</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="3">3</td>
                    <td colspan="3">4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

<button onclick="exportToExcel()">  
            Export to Excel</button>  


</body>
</html>
```

Below is the excel output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Praveen, I have already tried the code and it works, But the problem with the export is that my Table have Row Span and Col Span, which is not exported properly. Thats the reason I am not using it. If it is possible to achieve it using the same please do suggest me as I have already tried googleing it.

Comment: @Aditya Pewekar Hey can you please share the structure of your table , so that i can help you further.

Comment: have updated the structure in question. I have implemented server side but looking for a generic solution.

Comment: @Aditya do you want the excel export to be in same format as it is displayed in table ? If no then share the structure of your excel too..

Comment: I have already tried the above but my export dosn't give me output with the Row span and Col Span